# Uploading an image in one of the rendered list components only renders the first

Tags: php, laravel-livewire, alpine.js, laravel-10

I have a list of tasks that are each editable and have an image upload component. but if i upload an image in any of the components that aren't the first in the list it still renders in the first component. Also i use the spatie mediaLibrary for my image uploads.

livewire components:

ShiftShow

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Livewire\App\Shift;

use App\Models\Company;
use App\Models\Shift;
use Livewire\Component;

class ShiftShow extends Component
{
    public Shift $shift;
    public Company $company;
    public $tasks;
    public $return_link;

    protected $listeners = ['pullTasks', 'refreshComponent' => '$refresh'];

    public function mount() 
    {
        $this->company = $this->shift->company;
        $this->return_link = route('company.dashboard');
        
    }

    public function pullTasks()
    {
        $this->tasks = $this->shift->tasks()->get();
    }

    public function render()
    {
        $this->pullTasks();
        return view('livewire.app.shift.shift-show')->layout('layouts.app', ['company' =>     $this->company, 'title' => 'Dienst']);
    }
}
```

TaskItem

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Livewire\App\Shift;

use App\Enums\TaskStatusEnum;
use App\Models\Task;
use App\Traits\Timetrait;
use Livewire\Component;
use Livewire\WithFileUploads;

class TaskItem extends Component
{
    use Timetrait, WithFileUploads;

    public Task $task;
    public $description;
    public $status_item;
    public $task_status;
    public $status;
    public $active;
    public $file;
    public $associated_file;

    public function mount()
    {
        $this->active = $this->checkIfCurrent($this->task->shift);
        $this->status_item = TaskStatusEnum::getValues();
        $this->description = $this->task->description;
        $this->task_status = $this->task->status;
    
        $this->associated_file = $this->task->getMedia();
    }

    public function save()
    {
        $this->task->update([
            'description' => $this->description,
            'status' => $this->task_status,
            'finished_at' => now(),
        ]);
        if(!is_null($this->file))
        {
            $this->task
            ->addMedia($this->file)
            ->toMediaCollection();
            $this->file = null;
            $this->associated_file = $this->task->getMedia();
        }
        $this->emit('pullTasks');
        $this->emit('refreshComponent');
    }
    
    public function render()
    {
        $this->status = $this->task->status;

        return view('livewire.app.shift.task-item');
    }
}
```

corresponding blade components

shiftshow blade

```
<div>
    <a href="{{route('company.dashboard')}}" type="button" >
        <div class="inline-flex lg:ml-7 mb-2 rounded-full bg-indigo-600 dark:bg-gray-500 p-2 text-white shadow-sm hover:bg-indigo-500 focus-visible:outline focus-visible:outline-2 focus-visible:outline-offset-2 focus-visible:outline-indigo-600">
            <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" fill="none" viewBox="0 0 24 24" stroke-width="1.5" stroke="currentColor" class="w-5 h-5">
                <path stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" d="M15.75 19.5L8.25 12l7.5-7.5" />
            </svg>
        </div>
    </a>
    <x-base-container return_link="$return_link" >
        <div class="border-b border-gray-200 bg-white dark:bg-gray-900 px-4 py-5 sm:px-6">
            <h3 class="text-base font-semibold leading-6 text-gray-900 dark:text-white">{{$shift->title}}</h3>
        </div>
        <ul role="list" class="divide-y divide-white/5">
            @foreach($tasks as $i => $task)
                <livewire:app.shift.task-item wire:key="task-{{$task->id}}" :task="$task">
            @endforeach
        </ul>
    </x-base-container>
</div>
```

taskitem blade

```
<div x-data="{expanded: false}"  x-on:click.outside="expanded == true ? expanded = false : expanded = false">
  <li class="relative flex items-center space-x-4 py-4">
      <div class="min-w-0 flex-auto" >
        <div class="flex items-center gap-x-3" @if($active) x-on:click="expanded = ! expanded" @endif>
          <div class="flex-none rounded-full p-1 {{$status === 'not_done' ?
            'text-gray-500 bg-gray-100/10' : ($status === 'done' ? 'text-green-500 bg-green-100/10' : 'text-red-500 bg-red-100/10')}}">
            <div class="h-2 w-2 rounded-full bg-current"></div>
          </div>
          <h2 class="min-w-0 text-sm font-semibold leading-6 dark:text-white">
            <div class="flex gap-x-2">
              <span class="truncate">{{$task->title}}</span>
            </div>
          </h2>
          <div class="ml-auto" >
              <svg x-show="expanded"  class="h-5 w-5 flex-none text-gray-400" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" fill="none" viewBox="0 0 24 24" stroke-width="1.5" stroke="currentColor">
                <path stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" d="M4.5 15.75l7.5-7.5 7.5 7.5" />
              </svg>              
              <svg x-show="!expanded" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" fill="none" viewBox="0 0 24 24" stroke-width="1.5" stroke="currentColor" class="h-5 w-5 flex-none text-gray-400">
                  <path stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" d="M19.5 8.25l-7.5 7.5-7.5-7.5" />
              </svg>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
  </li>
  @if($active)
  <div  class="lg:flex lg:flex-col" x-show="expanded" wire:key='task_item-{{$task->id}}'>
    <div class="mr-auto mb-5">
      <label for="location" class="block text-sm font-medium leading-6 dark:text-white text-gray-900">Status</label>
      <select id="location" wire:model="task_status" name="location" class="mt-2 block w-full rounded-md border-0 py-1.5 pl-3 pr-10 dark:text-white dark:bg-gray-800 text-gray-900 ring-1 ring-inset ring-gray-300 focus:ring-2 focus:ring-indigo-600 sm:text-sm sm:leading-6">
        @foreach($status_item as $item)
          <option value="{{$item}}">{{__('status.task.'.$item)}}</option>
        @endforeach
      </select>
    </div>
    <textarea wire:model='description' placeholder="Bijzonderdheden" name="" id="" cols="30" rows="10" class="dark:bg-gray-800 text-white resize-none w-full lg:w-64"></textarea>
    @if(count($associated_file) == 0)
    <label for="picture" class="px-4 py-2 dark:bg-gray-700 bg-gray-200 mr-auto rounded-md mt-2 flex w-fit">
      <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" fill="none" viewBox="0 0 24 24" stroke-width="1.5" stroke="currentColor" class="w-5 h-5 mr-2">
        <path stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" d="M6.827 6.175A2.31 2.31 0    015.186 7.23c-.38.054-.757.112-1.134.175C2.999 7.58 2.25 8.507 2.25 9.574V18a2.25 2.25 0 002.25 2.25h15A2.25 2.25 0 0021.75 18V9.574c0-1.067-.75-1.994-1.802-2.169a47.865 47.865 0 00-1.134-.175 2.31 2.31 0 01-1.64-1.055l-.822-1.316a2.192 2.192 0 00-1.736-1.039 48.774 48.774 0 00-5.232 0 2.192 2.192 0 00-1.736 1.039l-.821 1.316z" />
        <path stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" d="M16.5 12.75a4.5 4.5 0 11-9 0 4.5 4.5 0 019 0zM18.75 10.5h.008v.008h-.008V10.5z" />
      </svg>
      Upload
    </label>
    @endif
    <div wire:key='image_element-{{$task->id}}'>
      @if($file)
        <div class="flex">
          <img src="{{ $file->temporaryUrl() }}" alt="" class="w-16 h-24 mt-2">
          <span class="ml-2 mt-auto">{{$file->getFileName()}}</span>
        </div>
      @endif
      @if(count($associated_file) > 0)
        <div class="flex">
          <img src="{{ $associated_file[0]->getUrl() }}" alt="" class="w-16 h-24 mt-2">          
        </div>
      @endif
      <input type="file" name="picture" id="picture" accept="image/*" wire:model="file" class="hidden">
    </div>
    <x-primary-button class="mr-auto mt-5 mb-2" wire:click="save" x-on:click="expanded = false">Opslaan</x-primary-button>
  </div>
  @endif
</div>
```

I tried adding extra wire keys to each component to try and force the image to show in the correct component but it still only renders in the first.

Answer (score 0):

you forget to add  ":"

```
 :wire:key=""
```

Comment: Adding ":" to the wire key results in the error: syntax error, unexpected token "<"

Comment: after removing task- it works but it still only renders the upload in the first component even if i upload it in the third one

Answer (score 0):

Problem is fixed after alot of searching i found that i needed to add `id="{{'picture-'.$task->id}}"` to the input the same to the label for to make this implementation work.